# Use Graphics Raycaster do implement pointer control VR

Tags: unity, gui, input, virtual-reality, oculus

I am trying to figure out how to allow my players to put in a code to join a group room using photon. Unity seems to suggest using a graphics raycaster but in most sample code it uses mouse input for the input data like in this example :

```
//Create the PointerEventData with null for the EventSystem
PointerEventData ped = new PointerEventData(null);
//Set required parameters, in this case, mouse position
ped.position = Input.mousePosition;
```

I have been able to interact by putting a collider on the UI element and a collider on the OVR Player's hand but how would I create a pointer like in oculus home to interact with the GUI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using Oculus OVR, so then you can use OVR Ray interactions ([documentation here](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-isdk-create-ray-interactions/))

If you instead wanna use Unitys XR Interaction Toolkit, your can use the XR Interaction ([documentation here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@2.3/manual/xr-ray-interactor.html))

There is also similar things for Microsofts MRTK ([documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/pointers?view=mrtkunity-2022-05)).

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included a short sample or summary of how to use those features, rather than only a link.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Jonas ! :)

Comment: Sorry @DMGregory, I don't get payed to answer questions here. Don't have time to write a long answer, thought that Doug could find the relevant answer in the always updating documentation them self.